# Wrong table coverage when running Jest tests in a React application

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, babel-jest

This is my Jest configuration:

```
module.exports = {
  "roots": [
    "../../src/"
  ],
  "moduleDirectories": [
    "node_modules",
    "src"
  ],
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "js",
    "jsx"
  ],
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$":
      "./mocks/file.mock.js",
    "^.+\\.(css|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
  },
  "setupFiles": [
    "./enzyme.config.js"
  ],
  "snapshotSerializers": [
    "enzyme-to-json/serializer"
  ],
  "testURL": "http://localhost/",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
  }
};
```

This is my Enzyme file configuration:

```
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

And this is the screenshot:

[image]

It seems like all the test are detected and passing but the files table is displayed incorrectly and I cannot figure it out.

Do you have any idea why this is displayed like that?

I run the tests with the following command: `jest --config devtools/test/jest.config.js --coverage --no-cache`